# Clean, safe way to auto restart (and monitor) daemons/services

Tags: server, services, restart, init.d

At the moment I am using init.d-scripts for starting services like TeamSpeak or MineCraft. Sometimes a server application stops because of some failure or it is auto-stopped, because of some plugin.

So, what is a clean way to check (like every minute for example) if a service is running and if not, restarting via its init.d-script?
Easy monitoring of services would also be nice.

Answer (score 1):

An external utility like [monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/) may be useful. You can have it monitor processes and restart them if they go down. You can also configure alerts if certain thresholds are surpassed. And it's available as an Ubuntu package!